# RequestDispatcher forwarding is getting rerouted back to the same Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, url-mapping

I have a servlet called `User.java`. It is mapped to the url pattern

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>User</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Inside the Servlet, the path following the slash in `user/` is analyzed, data about that user is retrieved from the database, set in attributes, and then the page `user_home.jsp` is to be displayed. 
The code to make this happen is:

```
            User user = UserManager.getUserInfoById(userPath);  
            request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("resources/jsp/user_home.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

The problem is, that rather than opening this `user_home.jsp`, the request is mapped once again to the same servlet `User.java`. It does nothing.

I've put output statements at the beginning of the `doGet` method, so I can see that the URL is

```
http://localhost:8080/myproj/user/resources/jsp/user_home.jsp
```

so it seems the obvious problem is that it's mapping right back to the `user/*` pattern.

**How do I get the Servlet to display this page without going through URL mapping, and properly display the `jsp` I need it to?**

Comment: `forward()` does not change the URL. Are you sure you're being redirected from `user_home.jsp` to `User.java` ? if so, maybe you should "clean" the request from certain parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the path passed to `request.getRequestDispatcher()` does not begin with a "`/`", it is interpreted as relative to the current path. Since your servlet's path is `/user/<something>`, it tries to forward the request to `/user/resources/jsp/user_home.jsp`, which matches your servlet mapping and therefore forwards to the same servlet recursively.

On the other hand, if the path passed to `request.getRequestDispatcher()` begins with a "`/`", it is interpreted as relative to the current context root. So assuming that the `resources` directory is located at the root of your webapp, try adding a "`/`" at the beginning of the path, e.g.:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/resources/jsp/user_home.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't want to use the `*` in your servlet mapping. simply because everytime that you have `/user/` in your `URL` it will redirect back to the servlet.

the asterisk accepts every `URL` that has `/user/` and redirect it based on servlet mappiing, so you might want to make it

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>User</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/user/User</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and use it in your `action` as `action = user/User`

Comment: What do you mean by `action`?

Comment: <form action = "user/User" ></form>

Comment: Ah ok. But there's form on the page

Comment: i mean so send the form to the servlet you may use the following `user/User`